# How to use xunit-style setup_function

Tags: python, pytest

**[The docs](http://pytest.org/latest/xunit_setup.html)** say:

*If you would rather define test functions directly at module level you can also use the following functions to implement fixtures:*

```py
def setup_function(function):
    """ setup any state tied to the execution of the given function.
    Invoked for every test function in the module.
    """

def teardown_function(function):
    """ teardown any state that was previously setup with a setup_function
    call.
    """
```

but actually it's unclear how you're supposed to use them.

I tried putting them in my test file exactly as shown above, but they don't get called. Looking closer at them, with that `function` arg they look like decorators. So I tried to find a way to do:

```py
@pytest.setup_function
def my_setup():
    # not called
```

I couldn't find anywhere to import one from as a decorator though, so that can't be right.

I found [this thread on grokbase](http://grokbase.com/t/python/pytest-dev/13bbzcq64v/running-finalizer-in-case-test-setup-has-failed#20131112immcomlmfhnvy5ay56rxkxud7e) where someone explains you can do:

```py
 @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
 def setup_function(request):
     # this one gets called
```

It works, but it doesn't seem related to the docs any more... there's no reason to call it `setup_function` here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just implement the body of `setup_function()`, that function is called for each function whose name starts with `test_` and the function is handed in as a parameter:

```
def setup_function(fun):
    print ("in setup function: " + fun.__name__)

def test_test():
    assert False
```

This will give as output, when run with `py.test`:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.6 -- pytest-2.3.5
collected 1 items 

test/test_test.py F

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________________________ test_test ___________________________________

    def test_test():
>       assert False
E       assert False

test/test_test.py:7: AssertionError
------------------------------- Captured stdout --------------------------------
in setup function: test_test
=========================== 1 failed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

The line before the last one shows the output from the actual call to `setup_function()`

A slightly more useful example, actually doing something that influences the test function:

```
def setup_function(function):
    function.answer = 17

def teardown_function(function):
    del function.answer

def test_modlevel():
    assert modlevel[0] == 42
    assert test_modlevel.answer == 17
```

This was taken from `py.test`'s [own tests](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/src/cba8287569b0e19d15436e2310b832b9315d0c84/testing/test_runner_xunit.py?at=default), always a good (and hopefully complete) set of examples of all the features of `py.test`.

Comment: thanks, it turns out I was suffering end-of-day code blindness... my test functions were actually inside a class (I checked this and just didn't see it!) ...making a `setup_method(self, method)` inside the class works perfectly, it was just me being an idiot

Comment: so how do you write a setup function only for a specific test?

Comment: @Tommy You make that part of the test, or you put the setup part in a separate function (which name doesn't start with `test_`, so it is not executed as a test function) and then call it from the specific test.

Comment: @Anthon thanks. I meant "specific tests" but the function breakout works. I didn't know if there was a setup function like this that you could call with a list of specific test functions as an argument.